# css tree menu won't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I am using a CSS Tree Menu from this site: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu

I can't seems to get it working in IE8.

In IE8 it shows the menu like below:

[image]

However in IE9 it looks like this:

[image]

In the tutorial on that site it says:

> This could very well work in IE8 but would require some JavaScript to
>   get IE8 to interpret the checked pseudo-class, which I won’t be going
>   into.

Does anyone know what it means by 'require some JavaScript to get IE8 to interpret the checked pseudo-class' ?

Or even know what is required to get it working in IE8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 does not handle pseudo classes, selectors combinators and such. Always remember that IE is typically a few years behind all other browsers in modern standards support. So we have to use javascript and some of the many libraries around used to fix IE, such as boilerplate or modernizer.